# Spring boot Required request parameter 'paramName' for method parameter type String is not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, java-8

I am writing a spring boot application. But I have exception as below

> "Internal Server Exception has been occured! Exception details: Required request parameter 'caseNumbers' for method parameter type String is not present"

Below is my code

**My Controller**

```
public interface ReadCaseByCaseNumberController {

    @GetMapping("/case")
    ResponseEntity<String> getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(@RequestParam String caseNumbers) throws IOException;
}
```

**My ControllerImpl**

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReadCaseByCaseNumberControllerImpl implements ReadCaseByCaseNumberController {

    private final ReadCaseByCaseNumberService readCaseByCaseNumberService;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(String caseNumbers) throws IOException {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(readCaseByCaseNumberService.getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(caseNumbers));
    }
```

**My Service**

```
public interface ReadCaseByCaseNumberService {

     ReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(String caseNumbers) throws IOException;
}
```

**My ServiceImpl**

```
RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReadCaseByCaseNumberControllerImpl implements ReadCaseByCaseNumberController {

@Value("${servce.urlBasePath}")
private String urlBasePath;

@Value("${service.getCaseByCaseNumberPath}")
private String getMessageByCaseNumberURL;

@Override
public String getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(String caseNumbers)

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        httpHeaders.set("key", "value");
        httpHeaders.set("token", "token");
   

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);


        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlBasePath.concat(getMessageByCaseNumberURL))
                .queryParam("caseNumbers", caseNumbers);
        
        ResponseEntity<String> readCaseByCaseNumberResponseResponse =
                restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);

        if (readCaseByCaseNumberResponseResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {

            return readCaseByCaseNumberResponseResponse.getBody();

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error log?

Comment: Also check you are using the right `@RequestParam`. Correct package is  **"org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam"**

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the method getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse,
When you build the UriComponentsBuilder builder it should generate an url similar to this one:
yourBaseUrl/**case?caseNumbers=someValue**

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have changed as s String body still same problem

Comment: You can start troubleshooting issue by trying to consume API with some other way like Postman or curl and finding if expected one `basePath/case?caseNumbers={somevalue}` is working. This way you can be sure that problem lies in server implementation. If URL works, then try to rectify code which is calling your API. I can see that there is probably a typo in `@Value("${servce.urlBasePath}")`

Comment: Entry<String, String> caseNumber = caseNumbers.entrySet().iterator().next(); //TODO refactor
        UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                .scheme("https").host(urlBasePath)
                .path(getMessageByCaseNumberURL).query(caseNumber.getKey() + "=" + caseNumber.getValue()).buildAndExpand();